# Large Half Lap Joints For "L" Shelving

Tags: joinery, router, jig, joints

Fairly new to woodworking and building some pantry shelves that go on two walls, forming an 'L.' See pictures below.

My question is what is the best way to rout these fairly large half laps? The half laps are 9-1/4" x 6-7/8" x 3/8". My router base is smaller than the size of the half laps, so there is nothing to support the base without falling into the routed area. I made a simple jig (see picture) that works but I have to reposition it multiple times.

Am I missing something, is there an easier way to do this where I don't have to reposition a jig multiple times?
[image: Half lap view one]
[image: Half lap view two]

[image: Half lap jig]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is what is the best way to rout these fairly large half laps?

There's almost never **a** best way to do things — and not just in woodworking — because different people will have different opinions based on various factors. For this task they might include:

- their router (how powerful it is and/or how fast or slow it can be set)
- tied in with the above, which bits are available that are suitable
- how much effort or time the user is willing to put into making a jig<sup>1</sup>
- how much scrap material is available at the present time.

Also worth bearing in mind that not everyone would do this by power routing in the first place.....

> My router base is smaller than the size of the half laps, so there is nothing to support the base without falling into the routed area.
> Am I missing something, is there an easier way to do this where I don't have to reposition a jig multiple times?

A larger sub-base<sup>2</sup> that would allow it to span a jig that would cover the longest dimension needed to do this in one shot.

But FWIW I think the jig you've built is perfectly adequate for the task at hand, and is more likely to have secondary usage than one made to cover the entire area of this lap joint.

**Note:** a crossing half-lap isn't ideal for a joint face this wide in solid wood, because it's a cross-grain situation and the two opposing directions of wood movement will stress the joint, and could cause other issues with your shelves over time<sup>3</sup>. A half lap of similar dimensions to this would be better reserved for man-made board materials which are dimensionally stable.

__

<sup>1</sup> *If any.* Some people are pathologically opposed to making a jig for a single project!

<sup>2</sup> These are very useful for a number of applications, and many are deliberately asymmetrical so a balancing handle can be placed way off to one side.

<sup>3</sup> Including warping and a tendency to pull the support brackets off the walls.

Comment: Thank you for this well thought out answer! I did not know about the cross grain issue with half-lap joints, but makes total sense. Might re-think how I am going to join these two shelves now.

Comment: There's an inherent problem with L-shaped arrangements in solid wood in that one piece wants to push against the other where the edges meet. Local conditions do play a big part here — if conditions are relatively stable, because of the local climate (no big swings in humidity) or from the heating and aircon in your home this might be fine; pine rather surprisingly has a relatively low coefficient of expansion. However, flat-sawn pieces do still maximise potential movement, and selecting rift- or quarter-sawn material would be better (movement is roughly half as much as flat-sawn) but it's $$.

Answer (score 2):

a) Just rout from the outside in. You should always have space for at least half your router base. You can obviously only take one pass as you are taking away the wood the router should sit on. But if you do it in the right direction there will always be "high" wood for the router to sit on. Since you can only take one pass, dial in the depth perfectly on a test piece. (I prefer to err ever so slightly on taking away too little rather than the opposite, makes sanding the assembled piece easier I'd say).

b) Take a piece of plywood, cut an inch or so off a corner and screw your router to the plywood (the bit goes where you cut off the corner). You basically extend your router base by however much you need. Similar to the jigs in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-iVeb6ob2g&ab_channel=JonathanKatz-Moses) video just with a bigger base. Like this you can actually vary the depth and take multiple passes. For the last pass to the mark go back to a) if you have a distance jig or guide for your router-bit combination. This will decrease your maximum routing depth by the thickness of the plywood.

c) This only works for the joint on your longer board: Use a table saw, preferably with a dado stack if you have one. Set cutting height to half your board thickness (dial it in on a test piece) and start cutting away.

d) Hand tools.

Personally I'd just go with version a) most of the times.

Comment: Thanks for this great response! I really wanted to use a dado stack for this, but I just feel like its a bit too sketchy because of the length of my boards and my lack of experience at this point.

Comment: Yes, be careful with the long board. Get someone to hold the end of the board or at least support the other end on a table or some rollers. Make sure you don't need to hold the board , this way you have two hands to support/guide the cuts. "Letting go" of the board shouldn't send it flying around or push into the blade at all.